# Linq: Getting subtotals for the inner objects with multiple nested groups

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I need to create some reports from a dataset retrieved from a SQL stored procedure. Here is a representation of the data:

```
+--------------+-------------------+-----------------+--------------------+
| CustomerName | CustInventoryAcct | ProductCategory | ProductSubCategory |
+--------------+-------------------+-----------------+--------------------+
| ABC          |             12345 | Books           | Fiction            |
| ABC          |             12345 | Books           | Fiction            |
| ABC          |             12345 | Books           | Non-Fiction        |
| ABC          |             67890 | Magazines       | Sports             |
+--------------+-------------------+-----------------+--------------------+
```

The dataset also includes many data fields related to the actual product that I'm omitting for brevity - the above are the four criteria I need to group on.

The report needs to group on each of those four fields, so using the above table the output would look like this:

```
Customer Header: ABC
    Inventory Header: 12345
        Category Header: Books
            Sub Category Header: Fiction
                Detail rows for each of the items in this group (2 using the sample data above)
            Sub Category Footer: Fiction (Item Count : 2)
            Sub Category Header: Non-Fiction
                Detail row
            Sub Category Footer: Non Fiction (Item Count: 1)
        Category Footer: Books (Item Count: 3)
    Inventory Footer: 12345 (Item Count: 3)
    Inventory Header: 67890
        Category Header: Magazines
            Sub Category Header: Sports
                Detail row
            Sub Category Footer: Sports (Item Count: 1)
        Category Footer: Magazines (Item Count: 1)
    Inventory Footer: 67890 (Item Count: 1)
Customer Footer: ABC (Item Count: 4)
```

I have a Linq query that is working for the grouping (not sure if this is the best way to do this):

```
var groupedData = rawData
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.ProductSubCategory, x.ProductCategory, x.CustInventoryAcct, x.Customer })
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.Key.ProductCategory, x.Key.CustInventoryAcct, x.Key.Customer })
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.Key.CustInventoryAcct, x.Key.Customer })
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.Key.Customer })
```

I use nested `foreach` loops to build the report structure:

```
foreach (var customer in groupedData)
{
    GenerateHeader(customer.Key);
    foreach (var custInventory in customer)
    {
        GenerateHeader(custInventory.Key.CustInventoryAcct);
        foreach(var category in custInventory)
        {
            GenerateHeader(category.Key.ProductCategory);
            foreach(var subCategory in category)
            {
                GenerateHeader(subCategory.Key.ProductSubCategory);
                foreach (var item in subCategory)
                    // Populate detail rows
                // Generate footer
             }
             // Generate footer
        }
        // Generate footer
    }
    // Generate footer    
}
// Generate footer
```

This part is working great - the problem is when I am trying to get the item counts for each footer. I can get the item count at the last nested level (SubCategory) by using `Count()`, but if I try that on the higher levels it predictably gives me the count of groups in that level, not the underlying items at the bottom of the hierarchy. I can't figure out how to drill down so I can create subtotals for each level of nesting.

I can get around this by using some `int` counters, but I was wondering if there was a way to do this in Linq. The difficulty I'm having drilling down makes me wonder if my grouping query is not the right way to handle nested groups in Linq.

I've read a bunch of SO answers and articles on using `GroupBy` but still can't figure it out - can someone help me understand the best way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that instead of doing 4 levels of `Group` up front, you do it as you go along. This way you can `Count()` each group to give you a sub total:

```
foreach(var customer in rawData.GroupBy(x => new { x.ProductSubCategory, x.ProductCategory, x.CustInventoryAcct, x.CustomerName }))
{
    Console.WriteLine(customer.Key.CustomerName);
    foreach(var inventory in customer.GroupBy(x => new { x.ProductCategory, x.CustInventoryAcct, x.CustomerName }))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"\t{inventory.Key.CustInventoryAcct}");
        foreach(var category in inventory.GroupBy(x => new { x.CustInventoryAcct, x.CustomerName }) )
        {
            // etc
        }           
        Console.WriteLine($"\tNumber of items: {inventory.Count()}");   
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"Number of items: {customer.Count()}");
}
```

Live example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/YtShT3

Comment: Thanks, not sure why that didn't occur to me! This helped put me on the right track!

Comment: Quick question - do you know how I would check if the iteration is on the last item in these foreach loops? I was previously able to do something like `if (category != inventory.Last())` but now I don't know how to refer to the collection I'm iterating over. I suppose I could use a regular for loop but if you have a slick way to do this I'd love to hear it!

Comment: @Jim use a `for` loop instead of a `foreach` and if the loop control variable is equal to `Count-1` you're on the last item.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication169
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("CustomerName", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("CustInventoryAcct", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("ProductCategory", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("ProductSubCategory", typeof(string));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "ABC", "12345", "Books", "Fiction" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "ABC", "12345", "Books", "Fiction" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "ABC", "12345", "Books", "Non-Fiction" });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "ABC", "67890", "Magazines", "Sports" });

            foreach(var name in dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("CustomerName")))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Customer Header: {0}", name.Key);
                foreach (var header in name.GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("CustInventoryAcct")))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("    Inventory Header: {0}", header.Key);
                    foreach (var category in name.GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("ProductCategory")))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("        Category Header: {0}", category.Key);
                        foreach (var subCategory in name.GroupBy(x => x.Field<string>("ProductSubCategory")))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("            Sub Category Header: {0}", subCategory.Key);
                            foreach (DataRow row in subCategory)
                            {
                            }
                            Console.WriteLine("            Sub Category Footer: {0}", subCategory.Key);
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("        Category Footer: {0}", category.Key);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("    Inventory Footer: {0}", header.Key);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Customer Footer: {0}", name.Key);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
  
}
```

Comment: Upvoted because you had the same concept that Jamiec came up with - this particular answer didn't work for me, I was getting an error when trying to use the Field<string> syntax...this app is on C# 6, is that a feature in a later version? Thanks for the answer

Comment: There differences between Jamiec and my solution is mine is intended for a DataTable.